# how to control request with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
# BEGIN 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END
```

I am a beginner in htaccess , so does any one help me to describe what is that lines means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little more in detail:

- **`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`**
   The contents of a [`<IfModule>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule) are only processed if the condition is true. In this case the enclosed directives are only processed if the module mod_rewrite is loaded.
- **`RewriteEngine On`**
  [`RewriteEngine On`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) is needed to enable the rewriting engine for that directory and its subdirectories.
- **`RewriteBase /`**
  [`RewriteBase /`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) sets the per-directory base URL path to `/`. But this is only necessary if the URL path is not the physical path.
- **`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`**
  This condition states that the requested filename (the  requested URL path mapped to the file system) must not be a regular file.
- **`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`**
  The same as the previous but it must not be an existing directory.
- **`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`**
  This rule will match any non empty URL path (more precisely: the requested URL path without the base URL path) and substitutes it with `/index.php` if the corresponding conditions both are true. Additionally it is flagged as the last rule, so when the rule is applied, the current rule processing will stop here.
- **`</IfModule>`**
  Counterpart to `<IfModule …>`.

Answer (score 2):

The .htaccess is rewriting all requests except for directories and physical files that exist in the rewrite base (the directory where this .htaccess lives, it looks like) to /index.php. This is a fairly standard practice with many Frameworks and Content Management Systems to achieve the "pretty" URLs (such as you see with Stack Overflow).

You might be interested in the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html), also.